# Почему Emmet разворачивает некоторые конструкции в одну строку без отступов?

Tags: html, phpstorm, emmet

Пользуюсь Emmet в PhpStorm, но наткнулся на непонятный момент. Иногда код разворачивается в строку, а не со всеми нужными вложениями и табуляцией
Например:

Если ввести такой код:

```
p>a.btn.btn-default{Кнопка}*6
```

то вместо ожидаемого:

```
<p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a>
</p>
```

Получаю все в одну строку

```
<p><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Кнопка</a></p>
```

В том же Sublime Text emmet раскрывается со всей необходимой табуляцией. Не подскажите в какой части настроек надо искать этот момент, чтобы все раскрывалось нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Сначала я вас огорчу.**
К сожалению, нет способа отказаться от подобной "помощи" в лице PhpStorm **стандартными средствами**. Ни для `Emmet`, ни для редактора (раздел `Smart Keys`) не предусмотрено соответствующих настроек.

**Почему PhpStorm так себя ведет**
Скорее всего, причина в том, что `a` является одним из [строчных элементов](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/strochnye-elementy), а это значит, что табуляция и переносы строк будут влиять на расстояние между элементами, что может оказаться неожиданным для пользователя.

Конечно, есть варианты со сбрасыванием размера шрифта и высоты срок, переходом на использование `flex` или обтекания, но PhpStorm не может проверить, используете ли вы какой-то из этих вариантов и идет по пути наименьшего сопротивления.

Все написанное выше предположение, но его легко проверить, оставляя ту же разметку, заменив только `p` и `a` на блочные элементы. В этом случае такого поведения не наблюдается.

**Решение есть**
Установите сторонний плагин "Emmet Everywhere" из репозитория плагинов.
Теперь если разворачивать подобные конструкции с помощью <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> все будет работать так, как вы ожидаете.

Конфликтов со стандартными плагином нет.
Особенность этого плагина в том, что Emmet теперь будет работать в любых файлах, где не работал стандартный плагин (например в файлах `.env`).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Видел этот плагин, но прочитал что PhpStorm имеет встроенный Emmet и решил не дублировать функционал. Как я понимаю встроенный Emmet надо отключить, чтобы он не конфликтовал с плагином?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Конфликтов нет, поскольку конструкции разворачиваются по другому сочетанию клавиш. Есть только преимущество. О нем в ответе.

Comment: ещё раз спасибо!